# How to send a postwalk-replace function to an agent

Tags: clojure

I am trying to send postwalk-replace function to an agent containing an s-expression.

```
(def myagent (agent '(+ (* 2 x) 2)))
(send myagent postwalk-replace {'x 3})
```

But instead of the replacement I get the following error:

> IllegalArgumentException contains? not supported on type:
>   clojure.lang.PersistentList

How can I send postwalk-replace and its arguments to an agent?

Answer (score 2):

`(send a f x y)` is the same as `(send a #(f % x y))` - it passes the agent's current state as the first argument to `f`. Contrarily, postwalk-replace accepts the replacement function first, followed by the thing to replace within. So, you will have to pass a function to the agent that intermediates between those to: `(send a #(postwalk-replace '{x 3} %))`.